# Column Tagging in GCP Data Catalog using DLP results and Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-data-catalog

I've been dealing with this issue for weeks. Does anyone know how to create column tags in Data Catalog from DLP results? I wanted to run inspection job on DLP and then tag the inspected tables with the infoTypes that I've inspected. I only found Java codes regarding this problem but I appreciate if anyone can help me with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a sample Python code that would implement column level tags. This [Tag()](https://googleapis.dev/python/datacatalog/latest/datacatalog_v1/types.html#google.cloud.datacatalog_v1.types.Tag) function from the Python Client Library could be useful. The complete Data Catalog Python Client Library documentation can be found [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/datacatalog/latest/datacatalog_v1/types.html).

**Feature Request**

However, you can let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access through their client libraries, and that you would like to request they provide a sample code for it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services. I'd suggest you make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Big Data](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655468&template=1284353), with the `Feature Request` template.

Comment: Might this tutorial provide a solution? ... https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/dlp-to-datacatalog-tags  (This may be the Java code that the original poster was asking about) ... now that I see they were looking for Python and not Java